# Big fish effects feedback needed

Tags: sound-design, music, television, broadcast

I wrote music for one program called Big fish and add some fx but I'm not sure whether they help it or not.

[vimeo]20887044[/vimeo]
What do you think about? Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your music and FX compliment it super well! Really awesome music and animation. Well done.

Comment: Thank you:) It is pleasure. Animation is not mine by this girl http://vimeo.com/user772083 We were work together for sometime.